# Losing quotation mark in ServiceStack service message sent from Fiddler / REST Console

Tags: json, servicestack, fiddler, servicestack-text

In RestConsole / Fiddler, I send the following RAW JSON Body

```
{"payload": {"pusher":{"fullName":"Boas Enkler","email":"info@it-design.biz","accesstoken":false}}}
```

Body Type is set to `application/json`. Now I've an entity like this

```
 public sealed class ProcessKilnPushRequest : IReturn<ProcessKilnPushResponse>
 {
        public string Payload { get; set; }
 }
```

The Payload property has the following string.

```
{pusher:{fullName:Boas Enkler,email:info@it-design.biz,accesstoken:false}}
```

so all of the question marks (`"`) are missing!

What am I doing wrong? How do I write the request body correctly?

Comment: Could be the same issue as described in [this post from a few hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197080/servicestack-returning-jsv-instead-of-json)?

Comment: Have you checked the `Accept` header and `format` query string param in your request, and the `Content-Type` header in the response?

Comment: @esker Well i try to imitate a call from kiln. The original call from there works and the " are included. Only I can't  get the call imitatet with Fiddler

Comment: Use Fiddler to capture the working scenario, then use the Compare feature to see how it differs from what you tried to send with the Composer.